# How to set external images as background for an app layout

Tags: android, background

I want to set an image which is in the sdcard as a background for one of my XML layout files. I think I should use File inputStream and outputStream as follows:

```
public void setBackground()
{
    try
    {
        String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/dir/FILENAME.PNG";
        InputStream ins = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[ins.available()];
        ins.read(buffer);
        ins.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.FILE_TO_BE_WRITTEN);

        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException io) {}
}
```

However I'm not sure that will work. I want some advice on it to use this way or could get a better approach to do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to...

1. Use a `BitmapFactory` to retrieve your `Bitmap` from a file.

   `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);`
2. Convert the `Bitmap` to a `BitmapDrawable`

   `BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);`
3. Set the background of your `View` using `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable)`

   `myView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yjay, That was cool. it worked. But setBackgroundDrawable() method is deprecated. Ain't this cause any problem for API level 16 or upper?

Comment: My apologies - that should be `setBackground(...)`. Answer has been updated.

Comment: It was also my question. I want to develop my code to support API level 10 and upper, but this feature requires API level 16 and upper. How do I get around with that?

Comment: Ah - if you want to support pre-API 16, as well as avoid any deprecation issues, you can compare the running API level against a target API level. E.g. `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)`. Note that this only works on Android 2.0 (API 5) and up.

Comment: replace with: BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

this is what you need. Loading a bitmap , resizing it and then putting it into imageview or set background of any view
[Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Comment: I read the documentation specially the section "Processing Bitmaps Off the UI Thread" but I don't know how to use it. Isn't there any simple way to assign external images to UIs?

Comment: That's the most efficient way. External images are big in size and dimension. that's why you have to scale it down and then use it. To fit the view. This operation is heavy thats why needed to be done on a different thread. If not you will always get outofmemory exception i guess.

Comment: That was a helpful guide. Sooner or later I need to get through. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If by external image you mean one that you provide, in the *res/drawable* folder, then you can set it as the background in an XML file using `android:background="@drawable/file_name"` right within the `<Layout>` tag:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg">
```

Comment: Yeah, that would work, but I want to get an external image from sdcard and set background programmatically.

Comment: @AliAllahyar ohh, ok. Then you may want to look at Prachur's answer. That may be what you are looking for.